# How to fix pdb in Aquamacs on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, emacs, debugging

I'm developing a django app using aquamacs as my ide. Pdb isn't working since upgrading to emacs 23.2.1 using python 2.6.1. When I invoke pdb like this:

```
M-x pdb
Run pdb (like this): pdb ./manage.py runserver
```

The gud-manage.py frame appears with this message (and nothing more) -

```
Current directory is /path/to/my/source/
```

It isn't responsive to keyboard input, though I can right-click and send a quit or kill signal. It seems like emacs isn't capturing the pdb output correctly.

Has anyone seen this and (hopefully) fixed it? I believe it has something to do with the [gud-pdb-marker-regexp variable](http://pswinkels.blogspot.com/2010/04/debugging-python-code-from-within-emacs.html) (see point #2 in link).

#### Related issues

1. [Seems to have been around since 2007](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs21/+bug/114933)
2. One person [a solution for this problem on Windows](http://pswinkels.blogspot.com/2010/04/debugging-python-code-from-within-emacs.html) (adding -u to the python command in the pdb script). I tried it anyway, but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue *(Current directory is ...)* to me with emacs 23.2 (9). As you mentioned, it is caused by a CR/LF ending and can be fixed by setting the `gud-pdb-marker-regexp`.

I added the CR (`\r`) to the `gud-pdb-marker-regexp`. May you want to add the following line to your `.emacs` file and give it a try.

```
(setq gud-pdb-marker-regexp "^> \\([-axx-zA-Z0-9_/.:\\]*\\|<string>\\)(\\([0-9]+\\))\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\|\\?\\|<module>\\)()\\(->[^\n\r]*\\)?[\n\r]")
```

Comment: That works! I'm on Aquamacs 2.2, which is based on GNU Emacs 23.3.1. I verified that this is still a problem, then applied your suggestion. Will you submit a patch to Aquamacs and/or Emacs? Thank you!

Comment: It seems there was an other solution discussed at [gnu emacs debbugs](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=5653#14) ... but nothing has changed [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob;f=lisp/progmodes/gud.el;h=47cbdf19ed2c448c7cbc4e695ce400e876d5e11e;hb=HEAD#l1562).

Comment: I added a comment to [Bug 5653](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=5653#29).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that is the case for you, but just to mention it: PDB hangs for me in Emacs when the source code path contains a space - when I move the python file to a directory without a space in the name, it works (on Emacs 23.1.1).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't have any spaces in my path.

Comment: This did work for me though ;-) !

(I am on Mac OS X 10.8.5, Emacs 24.3)

Thanks!!

Comment: I had this problem.  As a temporary workaround I was able to do the folllowing:  `(setq gud-pdb-marker-regexp "^> \\(.*\\)(\\([0-9]+\\))\\(.*\\)()\\(->[^\n\r]*\\)?[\n\r]")`

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same issue.  I had it fixed in 23.1 (http://debbugs.gnu.org/db/56/5653.html) but now in 23.2 that fix no longer works, or at least it doesn't appear to for me.  I've just submitted a bug to Emacs explaining the problem in detail and hopefully it will get resolved.

A workaround for this is to execute pdb from the emacs shell:

Open the shell: M-x shell 
Enter this in the shell: pdb

This will get pdb working properly within the shell.

Comment: I've been running pdb in a terminal, which is similar to your suggestion.